# What determines an interface's promiscuity, the interface flags or properties?

Tags: rhel, network-interface

I was running a scan with Lynis on a RHEL 7 box and it said that an interface was in promiscuous mode. I checked and determined that the links were not based on not having the Promuscuous flag (only Broadcast, multicast, running, and UP (BMRU) are visible):

```
$ ip link show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001

$ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface             MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0             9001 17217705      0      0 0      17899485      0      0      0 BMRU
```

So I looked at how Lynis was checking and it runs the command `ip link -o -d show dev eth0 | grep 'promiscuity 1'` and sure enough, I find the following:

```
$ ip -d link show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 8 numrxqueues 8 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

My question is which is more authoritative. I'm used to just checking the flags and not the interface properties. What does `promiscuity 1` mean? Is this interface promiscuous?

Comment: I don't understand your Q. Were you assuming that promiscuous = up + broadcast + multicast + running + up? Are you still assuming it?

Comment: I treid to clarify the question. No, I'm used to seeing the PROMISC flag, but I don't see them on this interface. I do see "Promiscuity 1" in the properties when I run ```ip -d link```, what does that mean?

Comment: I don't think that `ifconfig` will ever show `PROMISC` in flags. Nor will `ip link` show the `promiscuity` flag unless given the `-d` ("detailed") switch. And running `tcpdump` on any interface (which makes it promiscuous), and checking with `ifconfig` and `ip link show` supports that.

Comment: `promiscuous` is a separate flag which lets an interface receive all ethernet packets, including those which do NOT have its MAC address as their destination.

Comment: notice that your 1st `ip link` command does __not__ use the `-d` switch.

Comment: So the interface as listed above is promiscuous because it has the ```promiscuity 1``` output, even though it doesn't have the PROMISC flag? This is a production asset, and I haven't been able to replicate this in a dev environment, so I'm loathe to do too many tests on the production server, but I want to understand the meaning of this output. I guess the crux of my question is what does the promiscuity property mean, I've seen it set to 1 or 3 when the PROMISC flag was enabled, and I've seen it set to 0, 1, or 2 when the PROMISC flag was not enabled. Man pages are failing me.

Comment: `promiscuity 1` is just _how_ `ip link` shows the `IFF_PROMISC` flag ;-) An interface will be put in promiscuous mode by network monitoring tools like `tcpdump` or `wireshark`, but also by some vm software which "injects" packets directly into an existing interface, without using tap interfaces, etc.

Comment: Okay. Then I can assume this is a bug somewhere in the stack between the ip command and the network hardware. That promiscuity 1 without the PROMISC flag is an undefined state. If you post that as an answer, I will happily accept it. Do you happen to know what promiscuity 2 or promiscuity 3 means? Is that 2(or more)-bit property representing more than one flag relating to promiscuity, perhaps?

Comment: There's no bug -- the interface most likely _is_ in promiscuous mode, and it's probably because of something innocent like `tcpdump`. Promiscuity 2 or 3 (if ever printed) means exactly the same as 1: that the interface is in promiscuous mode. See also [this patch](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg225108.html)

Comment: This helps tremendously. In some testing, IFLA_PROMISCUITY is +2 when suricata/snort/tcpdump is running (and this doesn't show the PROMISC flag on the ip link output), and +1 when enabled explicitly (and this seems to always show the PROMISC flag on the ip link output). But I still can't replicate a situation where IFLA_PROMISCUITY=1, but the PROMISC flag is NOT in the ip link output.

Comment: According to the source, IFLA_PROMISCUITY is a counter, In further testing, it appears that suricata was incrementing this by 2, but tcpdump increments it by 1. So I was able to reproduce the situation I posted. Thank you so much for your time, patience, help, and knowledge. I'll accept any answer you post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [patch](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg225108.html) which introduced the `promiscuity` read-only parameter to `ip-link` / `iproute2`:

> the flag `IFF_PROMISC` is exported by the kernel only when the user set it explicitly, for example it will not be exported when a `tcpdump` is running).
>
> ```
> + if (do_link && tb[IFLA_PROMISCUITY] && show_details)
> +     fprintf(fp, "\n    promiscuity %u ",
> +         *(int*)RTA_DATA(tb[IFLA_PROMISCUITY]));
> ```

And in fact, the [`dev_get_flags()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/dev.c?id=1064f874abc0d05eeed8993815f584d847b72486#n6374) kernel function which is used by both the `ioctl(SIOCGIFFLAGS)` interface (as used by `ifconfig`) and by the rtnetlink interface (as used by `ip link show`), will *explicitly* clear `IFF_PROMISC` from the set of flags exported to userland:

```
 *      Get the combination of flag bits exported through APIs to userspace.
 */
unsigned int dev_get_flags(const struct net_device *dev)
{
        unsigned int flags;

        flags = (dev->flags & ~(IFF_PROMISC |
                                        ...)) |
                (dev->gflags & (IFF_PROMISC |
                                IFF_ALLMULTI));
```

[the `dev->gflags` above is a set of compatibility flags which are **not** used by the kernel, but only set and retrieved by the userspace interfaces]

The *only* way to check from the userspace if an interface is in promiscuous mode is (just as `ip -d link show` does) via the  `IFLA_PROMISCUITY` attribute retrieved via the [`rtnetlink(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) interface. That reflects the actual [promiscuity count](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/dev.c?id=1064f874abc0d05eeed8993815f584d847b72486#n6218) of the device: `promiscuity > 0` means that the device is in promiscuous mode.

---

Updating the device flags via `ifconfig DEV promisc` or `ip link set dev DEV promisc on` is not the only way to set a device in promiscuous mode: another way is via the [`packet(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man/packet.7.html) `setsockopt()` interface:

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, {.mr_type = PACKET_MR_PROMISC})`
```

That is what `tcpdump` (and other network capturing and filtering tools) are using.

Answer (score 0):

`PROMISCUOUS` is a flag by itself, not a combination of others one.

The flag isn't set on the dump you provided.

If i set it on my system manually, i can clearly see it:

```
~# ifconfig eth0 promisc
~# ip link show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:f1:0e:09:b8:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@NEO-L196:~# ip -o -d link show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether 28:f1:0e:09:b8:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
~#
```

If you continue getting the warning from Lynis, there's two possibilities:

- Lynis is buggy and reported you a false positive.
- Your system has been hacked and backdoor'ed: the hacker replaced `ip`, `ifconfig` and `route` binaries with patched ones that hide the promiscuous flag.

Comment: If we ignore Lynis altogether, why does ```ip -d link``` show promiscuity 1, but not the PROMISC flag? There are probably other possibilities as well, buggy hardware, buggy kernel, misunderstanding between user-land tools and syscall interface, operator failure on my part for not correctly interpreting the output...